# I'm sending my belongings by post from EU to UK ahead of moving. How to handle customs declaration?

Tags: united-kingdom, luggage, eu, shipping, relocation

I'm moving from France to UK soon and I wanted to send some of my belongings in a parcel to a friend ahead of time, so as to avoid having to travel with too many suitcases. When ordering the shipping (with UPS, if that matters) I was asked to complete a customs declaration. The form asks me for a list of all items and for their values.

1. Given that all of the items are used and don't have much resale value, how can I estimate the value to put on the form?
2. Do I actually need to list every single item, or can I include, say, "1 kg of office supplies" and "2 kg of used clothing"?
3. What happens if I mess something up on the form?

Comment: "Personal property with no commercial value".